# Сайт на Bootstrap 5 выглядит маленьким на телефоне

Tags: html, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>
Главная
</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500;800&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-white">

    <a class="navbar-brand text-center" href="/">ТестСайт</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/p/"><i class="fas fa-donate"></i> Статьи</a>
      </li>

      
      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>

    </div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        
    

    <div class="main__page">
        
        <div class="row">
            
            <div class="col">
                <h1 style="margin: auto;">Lorem</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
            
                <p style="font-size: 30px; margin: auto;">Ipsum</p>
            
            </div>
            
    </div>
</div>


</div>
</div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




</body></html>
```

Comment: Забыли тег meta viewport

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте внутрь `<head>` такую строчку:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Это сообщит браузеру о том, как именно обрабатывать размеры страницы, и изменять её масштаб.

[Статья на MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Viewport)

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил что этого нет